# How can I route all internet access through mobile broadband, and all corporate lan traffic through wired connection on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, routing

I'm on my laptop with a built-in 3G modem and an Ethernet NIC.

If I connect both, how can I route all my LAN traffic through the wired NIC, and all my internet traffic through the 3G modem?

I'm on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see *any problem* even with **default** Windows config for multi-homed system.

Route add or route change. route print for information

0.0.0.0 target must be assigned to 3G-interface, LAN-range - to Ethernet

Extraction of relevant part from my 3-interfaces host (DualPPPoe+2nd NIC) for 3 nets: home, ISP, Net

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.1.14.1       10.1.14.6       11
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     85.249.33.17    85.249.33.17       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.165.1  192.168.165.101      21
```

See at metrics for All-address
If you prefer GUI, you can do it in Network Settings - NIC properties - TCP/IP properties (General for mask + GW and Advanced for manual assignment of metrics for interfaces)